# Blazor Server - Local Storage after login

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, local-storage, blazor-server-side, microsoft-identity-platform

I'm working on a Blazor Server project using the default Microsoft Identity Platform.
My goal is to get/create a user in my db and save it to local storage after microsoft login is completed.

In the startup I'm sucessfully able to use the OnTokenValidated event to do some action after login. However it's not possible to write to local storage in this stage since the page isn't rendered yet.
I'd like to do something like this which is possible with Webassembly.

```
<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action" OnLogInSucceeded="SomeCode" />
```

Does anyone know a way to do this without using a solution like adding OnAfterRenderAsync in the MainLayout, which will fire on each page reload. I'd like to call a method after the Identity login redirects back to my site in a state where LocalStorage is accessible.

Answer (score 0):

You do need to put some code in `OnAfterRenderAsync`, but in this demo I've put it in `App` and check if the component has already rendered.

Here's a demo and some code to interact with LocalStorage.  You should be able to adapt it to fit your needs.

First a service to encapsulate getting and setting to Local Storage

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ProtectedBrowserStorage;

public class LocalStorageService
{
    private readonly ProtectedLocalStorage _storage;

    public LocalStorageService(ProtectedLocalStorage storage)
        => _storage = storage;

    public async ValueTask<CommandResult> SaveAsync<TRecord>(CommandRequest<TRecord> request)
    {
        if (request.Record is not null)
            await _storage.SetAsync(request.StorageName, request.Record);

        // No return so we return success!
        return CommandResult.Success();
    }

    public async ValueTask<RecordQueryResult<TRecord>> ReadAsync<TRecord>(RecordQueryRequest<TRecord> request)
    {
        // We need to cover the situation were the component calling this is in the initial page
        // and Blazor server is trying to statically render the page
        try
        {
            var result = await _storage.GetAsync<TRecord>(request.StorageName);
            return new RecordQueryResult<TRecord> { Successful = result.Success, Record = result.Value, Message = $"Failed to retrieve a value for {request.StorageName}" };
        }
        catch
        {
            return new RecordQueryResult<TRecord> { Successful = false, Message = $"Failed to retrieve a value for {request.StorageName}" };
        }
    }
}
```

The CQS Request and Result objects:

```cs
public record CommandRequest<TRecord>(string StorageName, TRecord Record);

public record RecordQueryRequest<TRecord>(string StorageName);

public record CommandResult
{
    public bool Successful { get; init; }
    public string Message { get; init; } = string.Empty;

    public static CommandResult Success()
        => new CommandResult { Successful = true };

    public static CommandResult Failure(string message)
        => new CommandResult { Successful = false };
}

public record RecordQueryResult<TRecord>
{
    public TRecord? Record { get; init; }
    public bool Successful { get; init; }
    public string Message { get; init; } = string.Empty;

    public static RecordQueryResult<TRecord> Success(TRecord record)
        => new RecordQueryResult<TRecord> { Record = record, Successful = true };

    public static RecordQueryResult<TRecord> Failure(string message)
        => new RecordQueryResult<TRecord> { Successful = false };
}
```

Registered like this:

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<LocalStorageService>();
```

My simple Data:

```cs
public record TestData( string LastSaved);
```

Add code to `App` to set as if you are getting data after login.  This implements a custom after render handler.

```cs
@inject LocalStorageService Service
@implements IHandleAfterRender
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p role="alert">Sorry, theres nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>

@code {
    private bool _hasCalledOnAfterRender;

    // implements a custom IHandleAfterRender handler
    async Task IHandleAfterRender.OnAfterRenderAsync()
    {
        // Only do if first render and the data in local storage is empty
        if (!_hasCalledOnAfterRender && !await GetData())
        {
            var newData = new TestData($"Saved at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}");
            var result = await this.Service.SaveAsync<TestData>(new CommandRequest<TestData>("TestData", newData));
            _hasCalledOnAfterRender = true;
        }
    }

    private async Task<bool> GetData()
    {
        var result = await this.Service.ReadAsync<TestData>(new RecordQueryRequest<TestData>("TestData"));
        return result?.Successful ?? false;
    }
}
```

And my test route/page to display the data.

```cs
@page "/"
@inject LocalStorageService Service
@implements IDisposable
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

<div class="bg-black text-white m-3">
    Test Data Last Saved at : @this.data.LastSaved
</div>

<div class="m-3">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=SaveToLocal>Save Data to Local</button>
</div>

@code {
    private TestData data = new TestData(string.Empty);

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await this.GetData();
        this.Service.StorageChanged += this.DataChanged;
    }

    private async void DataChanged(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await this.GetData();
        await this.InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    private async Task<bool> GetData()
    {
        var result = await this.Service.ReadAsync<TestData>(new RecordQueryRequest<TestData>("TestData"));
        data = result?.Record ?? new TestData(string.Empty);
        return result?.Successful ?? false;
    }

    private async Task SaveToLocal()
    {
        var newData = new TestData($"Saved at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}");
        var result = await this.Service.SaveAsync<TestData>(new CommandRequest<TestData>("TestData", newData));
        await this.GetData();
    }

    public void Dispose()
        => this.Service.StorageChanged -= this.DataChanged;
}
```